# Create and delete ingress for temporary containers

Tags: kubernetes

(I have just stared learning kubernetes, so apologies if my question sounds silly)

In my cluster I am running some pods that execute some batch operations and expose a webUI to keep track of the overall progress.

To access the webUI I am currently using a port-forward, but I was wondering

Is there any way to get a disposable ingress that is tied to the container lifecycle, in such a way that it is automatically created when the pod is started, and deleted whenever the pod terminates?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get a disposable ingress that is tied to the container lifecycle, in such a way that it is automatically created when the pod is started, and deleted whenever the pod terminates?

Is there a way? Absolutely, but be aware that's for sure not how kubernetes thinks about the world, so you are going to be fighting uphill trying to maintain a system like that. With that said:

### Helm

*This part I have done, extensively, and works as advertised*

The way most people manage groups of related resources is via [helm](https://helm.sh), which in your case would create the `Job` as well as the `Ingress` resource for it. When the Job has finished (a process that helm, itself, does not meddle in), you can remove all grouped resources in one shot via [`helm uninstall`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_uninstall/) which will delete the `Job` and its associated `Ingress`.

I believe it may be possible to hook the Job completion events with other machinery, but since this part is confined to things I have actively done, I wouldn't want to speculate on the "best" way for that

### Admission Controller

*this section is speculation, as I have not personally worked with this part*

Kubernetes offers [dynamic admission controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) which are *intended* to allow one to have very complicated rules about what workloads one allows in their cluster, but has the pleasing side-effect of being consulted before Pod creation (and I can only presume deletion) takes place. That enables you to run arbitrary code in response to those webhook events, and then just return "Allow" from the validating admission controller